# Py2app include lxml

Tags: python, macos, lxml

I have an application I am building in py2app on OSX Yosemite, which uses lxml. The built app throws an error on OSX 10.8.5. Here is the `setup.py` file I am using for py2app:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile':'AppleLogo.icns',
    'packages' : ['wx', 'lxml'],
    'plist': {'CFBundleShortVersionString':'6.2',}
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    name='iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2',
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And here is the error I am recieving when running it on OSX 10.8.5 machine with no extra modules or software installed.

```
-------------------
Application Error!
10-53-07_09-01-2015
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2.app/Contents/Resources/iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2.py", line 1781, in GetJobInfo
  File "lxml/etree.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "lxml/etree.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _xmlBufContent
  Referenced from: /Applications/iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/lxml/etree.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
 in /Applications/iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/lxml/etree.so
```

Can I make this work without installing anything else on the 10.8.5 system?

UPDATE:
I also tried this setup.py as well, still didn't work:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
                   'packages' : ['lxml'],
                   'frameworks' : ['/usr/local/libxml2-2.7.2/lib/libxml2.2.7.2.dylib'],
                   'iconfile':'AppleLogo.icns',
                   'plist': {'CFBundleShortVersionString':'6.2',}
                   }

setup(
    app=APP,
    name='iTunes_Upload_App_V6.2',
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

UPDATE: Ans here is the lxml version I am using:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> etree.LXML_VERSION
(3, 3, 5, 0)
```

UPDATE: just updated lxml to version (3, 4, 1, 0), but still have the same issue.

Comment: What version of lxml?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the lxml version.

Comment: I have just updated lxml to version (3, 4, 1, 0), but still the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 10.8.5 and it seems the installed libxml2 does indeed not contain that symbol. `nm -g /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib | grep xmlBufContent` comes up empty. Apple probably ships a newer version with Yosemite. Can you (technically and legally) bundle libxml2 with your app?

Comment: How would I go about bundling libxml2 with my app using py2app?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have never used py2app, but now I see your OPTIONS dict specifies the `frameworks` key twice, overwriting the first value. Maybe that screws up your build? Can you look into the built app and verify it contains all the dylibs you need?

Comment: I have updated the question again to include only one frameworks, still getting the issue. Is there a way to fix this?